# Data Execution Prevention - Optout for the exe in “C:\Program Files\SSS\sss.exe” using Command Prompt

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, batch-file, windows-command-prompt, vbscript

Can any one help me in adding `"C:\Program Files\SSS\sss.exe"` in DEP Exception list using Command Prompt?

Comment: I've tried looking for a solution before for Server 2008 R2 and never found any command line simple solutions.  It was just as easy to create a registry file with the appropriate exlusion values in them to run on the server(s) as needed instead.  http://www.winserverhelp.com/2011/02/add-dep-exception-program-application-windows-server-core/